# The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, full-text-search

I'm trying to do a fulltext search but it's not working in my web app. Here's an echo of the query and the error message:

```
SELECT name,id,city,state FROM campgrounds 
WHERE MATCH(name, city, state) AGAINST('camp' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Invalid query: The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes

I have converted the table to MyISAM and then dropped the index and recreated it.

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `campgrounds` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(145) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(145) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `zip` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name` (`name`,`city`,`state`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

If I copy the above query into MySQL Workbench and run it, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bonehead! MySQL workbench was attached to another server. I set it to my test server and the converted that table to MyISAM and all is good

Answer (score 0):

Clear the cache of your App (Memcache or query cache). Because if it works with mysqlworkbech then it should also work with web app.

Comment: I just restarted the server. But it's doing the same thing.

Comment: I'm a bonehead! MySQL workbench was attached to another server. I set it to my test server and the converted that table to MyISAM and all is good.